unable publish to maven repo due to spring-boot-maven-plugin
im trying to publish a project to maven central repository,but it failed,here's error msg:
Failed to process deployment: Error on building manifests: No Archiver found for the stream signature Details: No Archiver found for the
if i remove "spring-boot-maven-plugin" plugin, then it's ok to publish. can anyone tell me how this plugin effect the publish?
